# if $f(x)\le g(x)$ for all x. Prove that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) \le \lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ given the limits exist

Tags: calculus, limits, inequality

if $f(x)\le g(x)$ for all x. Prove that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) \le \lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ given the limits exist
I try to use delta-epsilon definition to prove that.. but it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: The inequality in the limit is nonstrict.

Comment: This is not correct, so it will be hard to prove.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The statement is equivalent to showing that if $f(x) \geq 0$ then $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) \geq 0$ provided the limit exists. Next, use contradiction and assume that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L < 0$ and use the epsilon delta definition to violate $f(x) \geq 0$. Think about it. If the limit is $L < 0$, then $f(x)$ has to get close to as we like, but that would make it negative.

Comment: ....Still can find a contradiction..Could you plz be more specific..

Answer (score 0):

The inequality in the conclusion has to be $\le$. Example: $f(x) = x, g(x) = 1$ on $[0,1)$, $a = 1$.

Suppose $u = \lim_{x\to a}g(x) < \lim_{x\to a}f(x) = v$. Let $d = v - u, \epsilon = d/2$, and let $U = (u-\epsilon, u+\epsilon), V = (v-\epsilon, v+\epsilon)$. Then for some neighborhood $X$ of $a$, $g[X] \subseteq U$, and for some neighborhood $Y$ of $a$, $f[X] \subseteq V$. Then $Z = X \cap Y$ is a neighborhood of $a$ such that for all $z \in Z$, $g(z) < f(z)$.